# Question tags when 'nobody' is the object

Tags: question-tags

As far as I know, the appearence of 'nobody' makes the question negative. So the question tag should be positive, right?

But what if the subject isn't nobody and the object is?

Example : I invited nobody.

What is the tag? "Did I?" Or "didn't I?"

Comment: You'd be better off recasting the sentence to a negative and using *anybody*: "I didn't invite anybody, did I?" As it reads now, your sentence sounds a bit unnatural.

Comment: This is a great question. If *nobody*, *nothing,* and so on, is the subject, it makes the question negative and the question tag is positive. But what happens when *nobody* is the object. My intuition as a native English speaker fails me in this case, so I don't know the answer.

Comment: It seems English teachers taught nobody the answer to this question, did(n't) they?

Comment: @PeterShor Won't it make a sentence negative if *nobody, nothing* etc. comes as the object? ***I found nothing.*** ***I met nobody there***. ***I received no information.*** Are these sentences not negative?

Comment: @mahmudkoya: Why do you expect grammatical rules to make sense? As I said, my grammar intuition fails for this question, so I don't know the answer.

Comment: @PeterShor you said *nothing, nobody* etc. make the sentence negative if they come as subject. My question is how they lose their negativity when they come as the object. My question is for clarification, not for argument, is there such a grammar rule?

Comment: I invited nobody, right?

Answer (score 1):

> English question tags exist in both positive and negative forms. When there is no special emphasis, the rule of thumb often applies that a positive sentence has a negative tag and vice versa. This form may express confidence, or seek confirmation of the asker's opinion or belief.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)

In your example, the subject is “I” and the verb is the (positive) “invited”. So the standard tag here is the negative “didn’t I”:

- I invited nobody, **didn’t I**?

However, this combination (inviting nobody) suggests a more combative reply to a false assumption, using a tag matching the polarity of the ‘challenge’ question.

> Unbalanced tag questions may be used for ironic or confrontational effects
>   - *ibid*

- Challenger: You invited nobody to the party!
- You: I invited nobody, **did I**? So what about him and her and them!

In any case, when trying to work out the polarity of the question tag, **only the polarity of the subject and the implicit or explicit verb (from the main part of the sentence) that the tag uses are relevant**. The polarity of the question tag doesn't depend on the object of the sentence.

As [@PeterShor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473824/how-to-make-tag-question-when-we-have-the-term-nobody#comment1144190_473827) notes, a negative subject such as *nobody* can go with a positive question tag:

- Nobody was invited, were they?

The key is to determine the sense of the question. If it is an assertion, use a negative question tag; if it is a denial, use a positive question tag:

- Assertion: I invited ..., didn’t I?
- Denial: Nobody was ..., were they?

Comment: I have problem with this. Do you agree that i didnt invite anybody to party is as same as i invited nobody to party?they have same meaning right? If you wanna tag the first sentence it would be did I. But how the  tag of second sentence is different from the first sentece however they have same meaning

Comment: @johnmac: there are lots of pairs of sentences that have the same meaning but a different question tag.  For example, *"I didn't take her home, did I?"* and *"I left her at the party, didn't I?"*

Comment: @johnmac Peter’s right. More to the point, the tag needs to relate to the polarity of the duplicated verb. The rest of the sentence doesn’t really have a bearing on the polarity of the tag.

Comment: @johnmac The *tag* has nothing with *nobody*. If saying *didn't*, you ask *did I?* If saying *did* (even by implication), you ask *didn't I?* So: *I* ***didn't*** *invite . . .*, ***did*** *I*? And *I* ***(did)*** *invite,* ***didn't*** *I*?

Comment: @Jason: That's wrong. Fill in the blank: *"Nobody did anything, ____ they."*

Comment: I think peter got my intention. When nobody is the subject of our sentence with positive verb added after we can easily regard the sentence as a negative and use a positive tag question.like this : nobody did something. Did they?. Nobody is subject & did is positive verb. But the whole sentence have a negative meaning so the tag would be positive. My main question is when sometimes that we have nobody as an object,there is different rule. Example : i kicked nobody from the class. In my opinion tag question for this sentence should be did i. But you guys say that tag is didnt i. Right?

Comment: @johnmac In "Nobody did something", the verb is positive, as you note. So the question tag would normally be negative. The 'negative meaning' of the sentence as a whole is irrelevant. Where "nobody" appears as the object of the sentence, it is ignored when working out the polarity (positive or negative) of the question tag.

Comment: @Lawrence. You are wrong about question tags when *nobody* is the subject. See [this web page](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/tag-questions), where two of the examples are *Nobody lives in this house, do they?* and *Nothing ever happens, does it?* [Also this stackexchange question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85106/nothing-is-available-is-anything-tag-questions-for-negative-sentences).

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. I may have overstated the case. The subject does make a difference. Thanks for the comment; I'll need to think about this a bit more.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps resolve the question, but in the "_I invited nobody, did I?_" example, I think a better response would be "_You're saying I invited nobody, are you? So what about him and her and them!_" – that is, questioning the assertion (that you invited nobody) rather than the inviting.

Comment: @TripeHound So, you think that makes a better response, *do you*? :P

Comment: @PeterShor You’re right. The tag’s polarity depends on whether the question is an assertion or a denial. Even the “Oh, I did, did I?” retort can be analysed this way; alternatively, a positive tag expects a negative answer, and a negative tag expects a positive answer.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest mnemonic is that whenever there are somebody, nobody,everybody, etc., gets " they " for question tag.

Example : Somebody calls you, don't they?

Though here " does ' works as a tag according to grammar rule, the pronoun of " they" make it "do' as per the Concord.

Comment: But "nobody" isn't the subject of "I invited nobody".